# CONSTRUCT into a named graph

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki, named-graphs

I am attempting to use a SPARQL Construct query to create a new named graph from an existing one. The database I am querying contains `http://graph.com/old` as an existing named graph. I am using **Jena TDB** as the database, accessed through a **Jena Fuseki** endpoint. The below query gives me an error:

```
CONSTRUCT
{
    GRAPH <http://graph.com/new> {
        ?s ?p ?o
    }
}

WHERE
{
    GRAPH <http://graph.com/old> {
        ?s ?p ?o
    }
}
```

If I remove the graph statement from the CONSTRUCT block, the query works perfectly, but I would like to place the triples into a named graph that I specify instead of the default one.

As far as I could find, the [SPARQL 1.1 section on CONSTRUCT](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct) does not say anything about constructing into named graphs. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just as SELECT queries are used when you are interested in getting a set of variable bindings back, CONSTRUCT queries are used you are interested in getting a model back.  Just as the variables bound in a SELECT result set are not put into any model or persistent set of bindings, neither is the model built by a CONSTRUCT stored anywhere.  You want to use SPARQL 1.1 INSERT.  The update features are described in [3 SPARQL 1.1 Update Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#updateLanguage).  Your update request can thus be written as:

```
INSERT {
  GRAPH <http://graph.com/new> {
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
}
WHERE {
  GRAPH <http://graph.com/old> {
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
}
```

For this particular case, though, you might be able to use the COPY operation described in [3.2.3 COPY](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#copy).  COPY removes all the data from the target graph first though, so it might not be applicable to your actual case (understanding that the code you provided may be a minimal example, and not necessarily the actual update you're trying to perform).  About COPY the standard says:

> The COPY operation is a shortcut for inserting all data from an input
>   graph into a destination graph. Data from the input graph is not
>   affected, but data from the destination graph, if any, is removed
>   before insertion.
>
> ```
> COPY ( SILENT )? ( ( GRAPH )? IRIref_from | DEFAULT) TO ( ( GRAPH )? IRIref_to | DEFAULT )
> ```
>
> is similar in operation to:
>
> ```
> DROP SILENT (GRAPH IRIref_to | DEFAULT);
>       INSERT { ( GRAPH IRIref_to )? { ?s ?p ?o } } WHERE { ( GRAPH IRIref_from )? { ?s ?p ?o } }
> ```
>
> The difference between COPY and the DROP/INSERT combination is that if
>   COPY is used to copy a graph onto itself then no operation will be
>   performed and the data will be left as it was. Using DROP/INSERT in
>   this situation would result in an empty graph.
>
> If the destination graph does not exist, it will be created. By
>   default, the service may return failure if the input graph does not
>   exist. If SILENT is present, the result of the operation will always
>   be success.

If COPY isn't suitable, then [ADD](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#add) may be what you're looking for:

> 3.2.5 ADD
>
> The ADD operation is a shortcut for inserting all data from an input
>   graph into a destination graph. Data from the input graph is not
>   affected, and initial data from the destination graph, if any, is kept
>   intact.
>
> ```
> ADD ( SILENT )? ( ( GRAPH )? IRIref_from | DEFAULT) TO ( ( GRAPH )? IRIref_to | DEFAULT)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> INSERT { ( GRAPH IRIref_to )? { ?s ?p ?o } } WHERE { ( GRAPH IRIref_from )? { ?s ?p ?o } }
> ```
>
> If the destination graph does not exist,
>   it will be created. By default, the service may return failure if the
>   input graph does not exist. If SILENT is present, the result of the
>   operation will always be success.

Comment: The alternative to `COPY` is of course `ADD`, this copies the data from the source to the target and preserves the target graphs existing data

Comment: @RobV Good point!  I haven't done much SPARQL 1.1 Updating, and I guess I didn't read far enough into the spec after finding COPY.  I'll add ADD.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use CONSTRUCT, you have to add triples to identify the named graph. One way to do this would be rdf reification.

```
CONSTRUCT {    
    ?s ?p ?o .
    ?statement 
        a rdf:Statement ;
        rdf:subject ?s ;
        rdf:predicate ?p ;
        rdf:object ?o ;
        ex:targetGraph <http://graph.com/new> ;
    .    
}
WHERE {    
    ?s ?p ?o .
    BIND(BNODE() AS ?statement)    
}
```

The constructed triples could be loaded into an other database and ingested into the target named graph by another INSERT.

```
INSERT {
    GRAPH ?graph {
        ?s ?p ?o .
    }        
    WHERE {
    {
        SERVICE <your-triple-store-containing-the-construct> {
            ?s ?p ?o .
            ?statement
                a rdf:Statement ;
                rdf:subject ?s ;
                rdf:predicate ?p ;
                rdf:object ?o ;
                ex:targetGraph ?graph .
            .    
        }    
    }
}
```

Why on earth would you do such things? As I said above, it is not always possible to use INSERT directly. I.e. it is not available in the context of [SHACL-Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-af/#rules).